# Why is "do" or "does" not used in questions with "which" and "whose"?

Tags: questions, wh-questions

I am struggling with subject questions. I understand the lack of do/does and did. I also know that this type of questions is formed only in third person singular, and we need to ask ourselves who or what the initiator of given action is.

I want to ask why there are no do/does in questions with which and whose?

Example:

> Which button opens the door?
>   Whose car broke down?

Is this another type of question? Maybe, Wh- questions?
I see that question "What opens the door?" and "What broke down?" belong to subject questions. So an answer to subject question will always be what (inferring from previous questions the answers will be The green one and Mine/My car?) and who? Can only who and what be used?

Comment: To clarify: do you expect "Which button does open the door?" to be correct?

Comment: "Do" is used in questions that have a yes/no answer, e.g. "Do you like opera"? Elsewhere, "which" "whose", "what" etc. serve as question words.

Comment: I don't know the principle, Patrick. It veries from questions with what and who.

Comment: Given examples vary from questions with what and who.(sorry for misspelling)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'why.'  It's just the way it is. Can you give an example of "what" with "do" or "does", as you are talking about in the your comment ("it varies")?